# QGIS map window rotation shutting off callout labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

[image][image]I have a QGIS map layout showing some callout labels.  If I apply a map rotation in the properties it inexplicably shuts off SOME of the callouts.  Does anyone know why it is doing this and if it is avoidable?  Please see attached images.[image: Non rotated.Rotated][image]

Comment: Please provide your label settings.

Comment: Not sure why the coordinate boxes are red.  They hold the drag out coords for the callouts.

Comment: Red boxes for data defined override indicate faulty targets. Please check those.

Comment: Yes, I have.  Multiple times.  They are yellow now and the problem is the same.  Rotate the map and some of the callouts shut off!

Comment: Have you tried the option show every label ? did the problem append only on manualy positionned label ?

Comment: I have tried the "show every label" toggle.  Still does it.  It only happens to that one layer though!  No other settings differ!  In the above example the Road and Well layer are labeled exactly the same but only the Well layer has the problem.